# Bash best way to extract var from multiple different string on different line

Tags: string, bash, extract

the output of my command is:

```
scan: DVD has 6 title(s)
...some text...
+ title 1:
...some text...
  + duration: 00:43:12
...some text...
+ title 2:
...some text...
  + duration: 00:43:12
...some text...
+ title 3:
...some text...
  + duration: 00:41:15
```

i want to have var for:

6 from `scan: DVD has 6 title(s)`

1 from `+ title 1:`

00:43:12 from `+ duration: 00:43:12`

not that the two last one are linked, maybe use an array For title and duration `title[1]="00:43:12"`

actually i'm only able to extract one information at a time but i don't want to run the command multiple time if possible. for example:

```
[command] |& grep -Po '(?<=DVD has )([0-9]+)')
```

maybe i should store the command output to a file first? what is the best way to start please ?

Comment: For just the parsing alone, let alone what you intend to do with the parsed data, I would recommend using a different language. `bash` (and shell in general) is not really meant for data processing; it's meant for process control and file handling.

Comment: Ok, so maybe i should store the command output to file (+/- 600 lines) and parse the file for different var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what you wanted to do with the values, but here's an awk script that gathers them and outputs them for every line of input:

```
yourcommand | awk '
  NR==1{ titlecount=$4; }
  /\+ title/{ curtitle=$3; }
  /\+ duration/{ dur=$3; }
  1{ print titlecount, curtitle, dur; }
'
```

Comment: Thanks, want to store values in array: title[number]="associated duration". Your awk script print lines that match + title or + duration several times, it also print a lot of empty lines, lines that don't match ?

Comment: @Eelisland I can't really tell exactly what output you want. Why do you want the values in an array? What will you do with the array?

Answer (score 0):

sorry my question is not clear. Based on your answer

```
cat DVDscan.txt | awk '
  /+ title/{gsub(":","",$3); print $3 }
  /+ duration:/{ print $3 }'
```

Output:

```
1
00:43:12
2
00:43:12
3
00:41:15
4
00:41:15
5
00:41:17
6
00:41:17
7
00:41:15
8
00:41:15
```

want to store the output to multiples array:

```
title[1]="00:43:12"
```

so i will know the total number of title and can access duration for specified title.

Thanks for your time and help.